# Get a count from all tables that start with ke in a single postgresl query

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I would like to get a count of how many rows are in 
all the tables on my postgresql database that start with "ke" in the table name.
I can easly get a list of all the tables that start with ke like this :

```
SELECT c.relname AS tablename FROM pg_class c
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON (n.oid = c.relnamespace)
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','') 
AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast','information_schema') 
AND c.relname LIKE 'ke%'
```

What i would like to be able to do is something like this

```
SELECT c.relname AS tablename FROM pg_class c
,(select count(*) from c.relname) as    total
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON (n.oid = c.relnamespace)
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','') 
AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast','information_schema') 
AND c.relname LIKE 'ke%'
```

but i get an error schema "c" does not exist.
I am not surprised by this but i would like to treat the column result as a table name.

How can i do that ?

I read that i can possibly use EXECUTE but i don´t think i can use that command ?
I would really like help on this problem please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ad-hoc things like this anonymous code blocks are a great tool.  The temp table in the code block will be dropped when the session ends or if you issue a drop table on it.  This is available in >=9.0.

```
DO $$
DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_counts;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_counts (table_name NAME, count BIGINT);  

     FOR r IN SELECT c.relname AS tablename 
              FROM pg_class c
              LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n 
                    ON (n.oid = c.relnamespace)
              WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','') 
                AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast','information_schema') 
                AND c.relname LIKE 'ke%'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO temp_counts (table_name,count) SELECT ''' || r.tablename || ''', counts FROM (SELECT count(*) as counts FROM ' || r.tablename || ' ) AS counter';
    END LOOP;

END$$;

select *
from temp_counts;
```

Comment: Use `quote_ident(r.tablename)` to safeguard against SQLi or undesired side effects.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, quoting is not a bad idea, but injecting sql into `pg_class`? :)

Comment: BTW, it was in original, but I think if you're making sure that namespace is not one of the listed, but you still expect it to belong to various namespaces it would make sense to put namespace name into query.

Comment: Oh yes. SQL incection via pg_class. Consider: `CREATE table "foo; DELETE FROM bar" (i int)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to create a plpgsql function to execute a dynamic sql.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION countrows(t varchar) RETURNS bigint 
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
 DECLARE
  rv bigint;
 BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM '||t INTO rv;
  RETURN rv;
 END;
$$;
```

then you'd use something like `SELECT countrows('mytable');` somewhere (perhaps just `countrows('mytable')` in your query, you don't need subselect).

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other way of doing this ? EXECUTE does not allow you to run select commands (if i read it right). And i get an error when i try to run EXECUTE. I get " function execute(unknown) does not exist"

Comment: Thanks for a good answer, your answer works for most users and is good but i am not allowed to create a function so this does not work for me so that is why i did not mark your answer as "The answer" to the question.